# Getting values from different worksheet with different workbook name with a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have many workbooks that calculates the sales, expenses and profits, each of them for different projects.

I want to create a file(let's call this master file) that gets the figures from all these projects so that I can work out the total profit and loss.

All the workbooks have their total sales, expense and profit figures all in the same cell.

So `K6`, `K10` and `K12` is the cells the figures are in for all the workbooks.
The workbooks have different code names as their file name.

I want to make it so that when I type the file names into the master file, it will automatically get the all the figures from these workbooks with the same file name. Then I would sum up all the figures.

This is as far as I got to get the value, but I keep getting an error.

```py
=INDIRECT("'"&\\serveraddress\filepath\filepath\&"["&cell that contains file name.xlsx&"]"&masterfilename&"'!"&$K$6)
```

I get `#NAME?` error when I type this in.

This is the master file. I am going to enter the name of the file of the other worksheet and the Code Column. Then the it's supposed to give me all the figures on the right columns which are drawn from that worksheet.

[image: So this is the master file. I am going to enter the name of the file of the other worksheet and the Code Column. Then the it's supposed to give me all the figures on the right columns which are drawn from that worksheet.]

This is the worksheet I'll be drawing the data from. These cells are fixed so they won't be edited in anyway. For different projects, I'll be copying this file and putting different details in it. Hope this helps in your understanding.

[image: This is the worksheet I'll be drawing the data from. These cells are fixed so they won't be edited in anyway. For different projects, I'll be copying this file and putting different details in it. Hope this helps in your understanding.]

Comment: `&` should be outside of `"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this -

`=INDIRECT("'\\serveraddress\filepath\filepath\["&cell that contains file name&".xlsx]masterfilename'!$K$6")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Adding the quotation mark is definitely helping excel to read everything.
But I'm still getting a reference error.
I think it's because of the "cell that contains file name".
I have that as C4 and when I evaluate the formula, the C4 doesn't convert to whatever value is in C4 but just stays C4. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: If possible kindly share sample excel data and an example. It will be easy to understand it.

Comment: Added "&" beside C4 but still getting the same error

Comment: Can you share a sample?

Comment: There isn't a sample excel data to demonstrate this but I think adding screen shot would help you understand it better. I'll get to it right now.

Comment: IT WORKS! IT'S MAGIC!!!! Thank you so much!!!! I got into making formulas in excel recently and I just learned a few things off the internet to make this. You are a saviour! Thanks again!

Comment: I just checked on the file again this morning and I noticed that I need to open the project file to be able to get the value displayed on the master. And this needed to be done every time I closed and reopened excel. Is there a way for this to update automatically or is this whole another matter?

Comment: `INDIRECT` doesn't work with closed files. You can search for `INDIRECT.EXT` in Google and install it which works with closed files. Also you can ask if someone can come up with some `VBA` or `Macro` to tackle this error.